# Can Microsoft Azure be used to run an Access VBA simulation model?

Tags: vba, ms-access, azure

I have some simulation models that I routinely use that were built in Microsoft Access VBA. I have just became aware of Microsoft Azure (I know I am late to the show), and was curious to know if there was anyway to run my model via Azure's distributed computing services to make them faster?

I saw something call SQL Azure on the website but I didn't entirely understand the product. 95% of the computation that exists in the VBA model are sql commands.

If you have any knowledge or experience I would love to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure is most like a remote SQL Server which - as you know - knows nothing about VBA.

But you can create one or more virtual machines hosted at Azure and install your application on this/these. Then, as needed, you can assign expanded CPU resources to these machines for as little as one hour.

Azure has a free tier. Create an account and you have access to quite some resources to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

While Azure is distributed, it also utility computing (that means slow in terms of processing ability and considerable amounts of “governing” in terms of CPU available).

The other issue of course is that running SQL on the cloud OS Azure means that any data you pull into Access/VBA has to occur over a VERY slow network connection. This connection is 1000’s of times slower than a local Access table.

So the real issue then becomes transfer of data. You could I suppose re-write the VBA code into t-SQL code and much dump the use of Access. However t-sql is even less suited to simulation type software than that of VBA (and procedural t-sql code is not that fast in terms of execution speed either).

So between bandwidth issues, and that of t-sql on sql server being a rather limited language when it comes to writing + running lots of procedural code (which most simulation software entails), then this approach is likely the wrong approach and wrong technology here.